# Ionic2-toast dismissOnPageChange not working when multiple toasts are shown

Tags: ionic2

I am using Ionic in version 2.2.1 and angularfire2 for log in. When the user/password is wrong I show a toast with following parameters:

```
this.toastCtrl.create({
    dismissOnPageChange: true,
    cssClass: 'toast-error',
    message: 'Email or password is wrong',
    showCloseButton: true
}).present();
```

Of course it could happen that the user doesn't close the toast, enters a false login info again, doesn't close the second toast either but then successfully logs in. Now it happens that a toast is still shown after page change (I change the page via `NavController.setRoot`), although I set `dismissOnPageChange: true`. My question now: Should I check if a toast is already shown before creating/presenting another one or should I open a bug for the ionic guys?